# Best way to make a linear regression model from a split .csv dataset?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, split, linear-regression

I'm generally quite new to Python, and I'm having trouble making a linear regression model. I need to make it from a training and test set from a large excel dataset (.csv).

I've split the dataset already:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Dataset.csv')
df['split'] = np.random.randn(df.shape[0], 1)
split = np.random.rand(len(df)) <= 0.75

training_set = df[split]
testing_set = df[~split]
```

How can I use this split data to make a linear regression model using the Mean Average Error?

Thanks.

Comment: Should that be Mean Absolute Error?

Answer (score 1):

With [`Scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/) is straightforward

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
```

Load dataset and split the data into training/testing sets

```
X_train = df[split]
X_test  = df[~split]
```

Split the target into training/testing sets

```
y_train = df.target[split]
y_test = df.target[~split]
```

Create linear regression object

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

Train the model using the training sets

```
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Predict target

```
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)
```

Print the coefficients

```
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
```

Print the mean absolute error

```
print("Mean absolute error: %.2f"
       % mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
```